# Display content based on URL

Tags: views, 8

I am working on Drupal 8. I have a to display content from a content type on different pages. I am trying to use Views to achieve this.

In the content type I added a field to refer to Pages so that I can create relation between content of content type and Pages (another content type). Basically its like tagging content with page name.

I want to display content from content type created on those pages tagged in the content. I am not able to achieve using views.

Any ideas how this can be done? I have tried contextual filter and relationship but none works.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So, basically, you want to a page showing those nodes for which the reference field points to a page with the same page title. Did I get it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as an example the taxonomy term view, which is in the D8 standard installation:

```
admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term
```

Two steps are necessary. First define the parameter in the path. For the taxonomy term this is:

```
Path

taxonomy/term/%
 ‎
This view will be displayed by visiting this path on your site. You may use "%" in your URL to represent values that will be used for contextual filters: For example, "node/%/feed". If needed you can even specify named route parameters like taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term
```

Then add a contextual filter in the advanced section, which will process this parameter:

```
CONTEXTUAL FILTERS
Add contextual filters
Content: Has taxonomy term ID
```

For the details see the example in your drupal installation. In your case you would use the referenced Pages node id.

If you want to use the view as a block, you cannot define the parameter in the path setting of the page. Then you have to switch in the contextual filter to "Provide default parameter" and configure the parameter from URL.

Comment: If I get what the OP is saying, the difference is that for a vocabulary, there is just a single taxonomy term with a given _title_. With a content type, you can have different nodes with the same the title.

Comment: I don't see _title_ mentioned in the question, but the URL should always match a single node, even if there are different nodes with the same title.

Comment: The OP says _Basically its like tagging content with page name._ Since the OP uses _page_ to mean a content type, I take _page name_ is the node title. The difference is between nodes and taxonomy terms, though.

Comment: In this case the example taxonomy term should lead in the right direction. You should make relationships with entity references, if it is a term or a node. Not with the title, because this is not unique and if modified you loose the relation.

Comment: I don't mean the answer is wrong. I just mean there are probably some differences the OP should know of.